# How can I pass CSS classes to React children and ensure they will override the child’s local class?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a `<Parent />` component with a single `<Child />`:

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

I want to pass a CSS class from the parent into the `<Child />`, so I do this:

```
<Parent>
    <Child className={ styles.pill } />
</Parent>
```

The `<Child />` has a `className` prop and applies the class using the [classnames package](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), like this:

```
<div className={ classNames(styles.pill, props.className) } />
```

But you see the `<Child />` has a class called `styles.pill` with these styles:

```
.pill {
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--grey__text--dark);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

The class the parent passed in contains these styles:

```
.pill {
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

With this setup I can’t guarantee that the styles passed in from the parent will override the styles within the `<Child />` component, which is exactly what I want them to do. Currently you never know *which* will trump the other. It’s seemingly random with every build of the project.

How can I ensure that the CSS properties in class passed in from the parent override any similar properties in the Child component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a matter of [CSS specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), there are many ways to insure the override.

1. **Multiple selector** trick, in order to enlarge the specificity you can double the selector size by duplicating the class name, in you case, `.pill.pill { ...}` will be more specific than the original, and therefore will override the style.
2. **Usage of `!important`**, you can specify that in the class of the parent, `.pill`'s declaration will contain `!important` at the end.
3. **Multiple different selectors**, the parent will pass additional different `className`, that child component will address, `.pill.parent-pill {...}`, the parent will pass the `.parent-pill` class to the child.

Those are just 3 easy ways to override the child styles there are more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` to merge one/many objects into a target object, giving precedence to each subsequent object:

```js
const foo = { a: '1', b: '2' }
const bar = { a: '3' }
console.log(Object.assign(foo, bar));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using CSS Modules which return only the new class name, no objects.